# How to normalize/reduce time data in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm storing minutely performance data in MongoDB, each collection is a type of performance report, and each document is the measurement at that point in time for the port on the array:

```
{
  "DateTime" : ISODate("2012-09-28T15:51:03.671Z"),
  "array_serial" : "12345",
  "Port Name" : "CL1-A",
  "metric" : 104.2
}
```

There can be up to 128 different "Port Name" entries per "array_serial".

As the data ages I'd like to be able to average it out over increasing time spans:

- Up to 1 Week : minute
- 1 Week to 1 month : 5 minute
- 1 - 3 months: 15 minute

etc.. 
Here's how I'm averaging the times so that they can be reduced :

```
var resolution = 5; // How many minutes to average over     
var map = function(){
        var coeff = 1000 * 60 * resolution;
        var roundTime = new Date(Math.round(this.DateTime.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);
        emit(roundTime, { value : this.metric, count: 1 } );
 };
```

I'll be summing the values and counts in the reduce function, and getting the average in the finalize funciton.

As you can see this would average the data for just the time leaving out the "Port Name" value, and I need to average the values over time for each "Port Name" on each "array_serial".

So how can I include the port name in the above map function? Should the key for the emit be a compound "array_serial,PortName,DateTime" value that I split later? Or should I use the query function to query for each distinct serial, port and time? Am I storing this data in the database correctly?

Also, as far as I know this data gets saved out to it's own collection, what's the standard practice for replacing the data in the collection with this averaged data?

---

Is this what you mean Asya? Because it's not grouping the documents rounded to the lower 5 minute (btw, I changed 'DateTime' to 'datetime'):

```
    $project: {
                "year" : { $year : "$datetime" },
                "month" : { $month : "$datetime" },
                "day" : { $dayOfMonth : "$datetime" },
                "hour" : { $hour : "$datetime" },
                "minute" : { $mod : [ {$minute : "$datetime"}, 5] },
                array_serial: 1,
                port_name: 1,
                port_number: 2,
                metric: 1
}
```

From what I can tell the "$mod" operator will return the remainder of the minute divided by five, correct?

This would really help me if I could get the aggregation framework to do this operation rather than mapreduce.

Comment: you really should use aggregation framework for this rather than map/reduce.  You can do it with map/reduce you just need to emit both port and time value as the key.  Aggregation framework would make it much simpler.  Are you using 2.2?

Comment: I am using 2.2, I haven't started to look into the aggregation framework, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: are your datapoints uniform?  i.e. over 60 minutes are you guaranteed to get the same number of measurements?  and are measurements absolute?  not relative to the previous one or next one, yes?are your datapoints uniform?  i.e. over 60 minutes are you guaranteed to get the same number of measurements?  and are measurements absolute?  not relative to the previous one or next one, yes? You see the problem, right?  If you get a high measurement once and low ones 10 times during the hour, if it's not for same time period each then you should weigh them, not do a straight average.

Comment: Each datapoint is the absolute average value over that period (in this case 1 minute). You're right though I may not get 60 data points per hour (sometimes the collector misses a point and doesn't store it) so should I throw out that point in time, give it a value of zero, or average out the values on either side of the missing values and assign that value?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - how would this get done in the aggregation framework? I'm not sure I understand it well enough. Where would one average the time to the intervals and get an average of the metric for each of those times?

Comment: Depending on how you wanted to treat missing minute values, you could do a straight average in the aggregation framework over time period. I'll post an example as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could do it in aggregation framework.  I'm using a small simplification - I'm only grouping on Year, Month and Date - in your case you will need to add hour and minute for the finer grained calculations.  You also have a choice about whether to do weighted average if the point distribution is not uniform in the data sample you get.

```
project={"$project" : {
        "year" : {
            "$year" : "$DateTime"
        },
        "month" : {
            "$month" : "$DateTime"
        },
        "day" : {
            "$dayOfWeek" : "$DateTime"
        },
        "array_serial" : 1,
        "Port Name" : 1,
        "metric" : 1
    }
};
group={"$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : "$array_serial",
            "P" : "$Port Name",
            "y" : "$year",
            "m" : "$month",
                    "d" : "$day"
        },
        "avgMetric" : {
            "$avg" : "$metric"
        }
    }
};

db.metrics.aggregate([project, group]).result
```

I ran this with some random sample data and got something of this format:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : "12345",
            "P" : "CL1-B",
            "y" : 2012,
            "m" : 9,
            "d" : 6
        },
        "avgMetric" : 100.8
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : "12345",
            "P" : "CL1-B",
            "y" : 2012,
            "m" : 9,
            "d" : 7
        },
        "avgMetric" : 98
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : "12345",
            "P" : "CL1-A",
            "y" : 2012,
            "m" : 9,
            "d" : 6
        },
        "avgMetric" : 105
    }
]
```

As you can see this is one result per array_serial, port name, year/month/date combination.  You can use $sort to get them into the order you want to process them from there.

Here is how you would extend the project step to include hour and minute while rounding minutes to average over every five minutes:

```
{
    "$project" : {
        "year" : {
            "$year" : "$DateTime"
        },
        "month" : {
            "$month" : "$DateTime"
        },
        "day" : {
            "$dayOfWeek" : "$DateTime"
        },
        "hour" : {
            "$hour" : "$DateTime"
        },
        "fmin" : {
            "$subtract" : [
                {
                    "$minute" : "$DateTime"
                },
                {
                    "$mod" : [
                        {
                            "$minute" : "$DateTime"
                        },
                        5
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "array_serial" : 1,
        "Port Name" : 1,
        "metric" : 1
    }
}
```

Hope you will be able to extend that to your specific data and requirements.

Comment: Sure this works for averaging times for hourly, or monthly, but can this technique be used to average over five minute periods? Can you round the datetime in $project to an average?

Comment: Absolutely.  In the projection do the same thing for $hour but for $minute use the $mod operator with $mod:["$min",5] to "round" all minutes to next lower 5 or 0 minute.

Comment: Ah wonderful, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your continued help Asya!

Comment: Are you using "$min" to mean the $min operator or the $minute operator? I guess I'm not seeing how this will "round" a minute value... can you be more verbose?

Comment: Asya, I've added more detail to the above question, I don't think $mod is the right way to do this... I need to round the minute down to the nearest 5 minute value, is there a way to do this in the aggregation framework? 

Math.floor("$minute"/5)*5

Comment: yeah the expression is slightly more complex, I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

"what's the standard practice for replacing the data in the collection with this averaged data?"

The standard practice is to keep the original data and to store all derived data separately.

In your case it means:

- Don't delete the original data
- Use another collection (in the same MongoDB database) to store average values