# mongodb: How to sample large data-set in a controlled way

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to generate the dataset for latency vs time dataset for graphing.

Dataset has thousands to couple million entries that looks like this: 
[{"time_stamp":,"latency_axis":},...}

Querying and generating graphs has poor performance with full dataset for obvious reasons. An analogy is like loading large JPEG,  first sample a rough fast image, then render the full image.

How can this be achieved from mongodb query efficiently while providing a rough but accurate representation of dataset with respect to time. My ideas is to organize documents into time buckets each covering a constant range of time, return the 1st, 2nd, 3rd results iteratively until all results finish loading. However, there is a no trivial or intuitive way to implement this prototype efficiently.

Can anyone provide guide/solution/suggestion regarding this situation?

Thanks

Notes for zamnuts: 
A quick sample with very small dataset of what we are trying to achieve is: http://baker221.eecg.utoronto.ca:3001/pages/latencyOverTimeGraph.html
We like to dynamically focus on specific regions. Our goal is to get good representation but avoid loading all of the dataset, at the same time have reasonable performance.

DB: mongodb Server: node.js Client: angular + nvd3 directive (proof of concept, will likely switch to d3.js for more control).

Comment: Where is the performance hindered: on the Node.js processing side, or the mongodb query itself? Is it because of the large result set being passed to node, or is MongoDB really acting sluggish when querying the result? Also, why do you want to display thousands of data points on the graph (there aren't enough horizontal pixels to even show that many data points)? Perhaps what you want to do is average (or mean/min/max) `latency_axis` over a given time period. Consider [Schema design for time series data](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb)

Comment: See SO question [How to normalize/reduce time data in mongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662169/how-to-normalize-reduce-time-data-in-mongodb)

Comment: So this is now either a D3-specific question, or this question should be updated with notes about what you're doing with D3. Are you rendering a full-resolution vector SVG with all the data points? If so, how do you expect the client to be able to work with that many data points? I still would narrow your resolution and/or average it and only send what is necessary for the specific view in D3.

Comment: Both the mongodb and nodejs is pretty fast consider the amount of data. The performance bottleneck is primarily in D3.js (graph generation). Currently mongodb returns the results in a little over 20 seconds and node passes to client side under 10s, but because I would like a preview or a snapshot of the graph very quickly, I don't need the whole dataset. I'd like a good "representation" of the data within 100ms. A clever use of index would probably reduce the data mongodb need to go through. Something similar to db.collection.find({i:{$mod:[10000,0]}}) would be perfect if it can use indexes